# Can you pull information from another sheet dynamically such that it is effectively a join?

Tags: google-sheets

I am tracking my stock purchases using Google sheets. I have separated the stocks that I have purchased into their own sheets and have an overview page

[image]

I want the data in the external sheets to automatically populate the overview list, where the overview stays up to date with the source sheets, and remain sorted by date.

This is the outcome I am looking for, though I made it manually:

[image]

Example sheet:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1okVUHw7DKDbzIwNHE1f38Ew81dEO_n27nrgyYV9zLzs/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Please share a sample sheet so that we can work on that. Otherwise we have to type data manually and many visitor will not do it.

Comment: Added an example sheet, is it enough to add link holders as viewers? Apologise, I am still new to GSheet permissions

Answer (score 1):

Try below query formula. See the sheet link `harun24hr`.

```
=QUERY({QUERY({VAP.ASX!A2:A,INDEX(SUBSTITUTE(VAP.ASX!G2:I2&SEQUENCE(ROWS(VAP.ASX!A2:A),1,1,0),"1","")),VAP.ASX!B2:E},"where Col1 is not null",0);
QUERY({UMAX.ASX!A2:A,INDEX(SUBSTITUTE(UMAX.ASX!G2:I2&SEQUENCE(ROWS(UMAX.ASX!A2:A),1,1,0),"1","")),UMAX.ASX!B2:E},"where Col1 is not null",0)},"order by Col1",0)
```

[Google-sheet Link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1LISMBNBfGLvjkKwEv3btHD9gTP5oJEQwpEXDdzGY8eg/edit?usp=sharing)

[image]